# HTML5 Manifest only see fallback

Tags: html, application-cache, cache-manifest

Hey guys my Manifest is as follows:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
images/trunk/text/text-images.png
css/site.css

FALLBACK:
/ offline.html

NETWORK:
*
```

I've since fixed a random random problem whereby safari couldn't load google maps without NETWORK *. What I now want to do is ensure that if someone is offline they only ever hit that offline.html page, I've noticed its possible to sometimes hit a regular page, which looks relaly broken and then you only get transferred to the fallback page after requesting another page. Is tehre anything I need to add here?

Comment: you can debug it [Blog Post](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)